# cocos2d: ERROR: Failed to compile vertex shader when upgrading to cocos2d 2.0

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to upgrade my cocos2d 1.0 app to use the new cocos2d 2.0 framework.

I followed the migration wiki and was able to get most everything converted.
but I'm seeing this error -
cocos2d: ERROR: Failed to compile vertex shader

when I try to use a simple CCLableTTF.
I'm not using any shaders or special graphics.
I'm sure I'm just missing something simple but can't seem to find the answer.

```
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSizeInPixels];
//# Moves Label
self.scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Moves: %d",self.player.score] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:18];
[self.scoreLabel setPosition: ccp(size.width/2, 400)];

[self.scoreLabel setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];
[self addChild:self.scoreLabel z:200];
```

I end up with a blank page and see the errors -

```
-[CCGLProgram initWithVertexShaderByteArray:fragmentShaderByteArray:] [Line 82] cocos2d: ERROR: Failed to compile vertex shader
-[CCGLProgram initWithVertexShaderByteArray:fragmentShaderByteArray:] [Line 91] cocos2d: ERROR: Failed to compile fragment shader
-[CCGLProgram link] [Line 178] cocos2d: ERROR: Failed to link program: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old cocos2d folder before re-adding a new one. Do not just copy over the new cocos2d files over the old ones.

Otherwise there's always the chance that removed or renamed classes remain in your project, which can cause all kinds of seemingly weird issues.